# Qpython - Not executable when run a script

Tags: python, genymotion, qpython

I have the Genymotion emulator and I installed the Qpython app from its apk (found it on internet). I moved the script "qpy.py" in folder 
 "/storage/emulated/0/com.hipipal.qpyplus/scripts" and tried to run it from qpython command line.

However, I get an error:

> data/data/com.hipipal.qpyplus/files/bin/python : not executable :
>   magic 7F45

This also happens when I try to run eg:

```
hello_world.py
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Try going to your hello_world.py file, right click -> properties -> permissions -> allow to make executable